# Highchart adjust timezone

Tags: highcharts, timezone

I am using HighChart dynamic graph. I'm in UTC +3 now.
My script is like:

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
            global : {
                useUTC : false
            }
        });
```

But when I run my code time is one hour more. For example now time is:11:36 but in graph time is: 12:36. How I can change it?

Comment: Use timezoneOffset http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/global.timezoneOffset

Comment: I used and It is works. But the other problem is I have two chart in page. One of this dynamic chart and other one is time series, zoomable. but when I use timezoneOffset my dynamic graph is work well but my time series graph was working well after timezoneOffset showing 2 hours later. Time is 13:10 now but in time series graph, time is 15:10 now

Comment: You can use setOptions twice. One before each chart to change the timezone offset.